# How to make one process to zombie

Tags: process, zombie

The question is the title, With one example please show how to make one of the process zombie between all process ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand your question as willing to make an already running process Zombie.

As per the definition of [Zombie process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process), it is not an easy task to make a already running process a Zombie.
A Zombie process is a process which is terminated but its parent things that it is yet running so its PID is yet present in the processes list, but actually the child process itself is stopped and no more loaded into memory.

There is no such action at OS level that would tell a process to go into "Zombie mode".
If you think of a command like `kill -ZOMBIE <pid>`, no, this is not existing.

If you want to create Zombie processes on your system for some testing purpose, you can use the example given on the Wikipedia page about [the Zombie process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process#Examples), I tested it and it is really creating Zombie processes.